Firefox не может установить соединение с сервером ws://127.0.0.1:8000/message
я определил следующих клиентов и сервер:
#это Flask и библиотека flask_sock
        @sock.route('/message')
        def echo(sock):
            while True:
                #data = sock.receive()
                sock.send(["I love DOG!!!"])
                sleep(1)

    const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.host+ '/message');
    socket.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
        console.log("Message from server ", event.data);
      });

Однако  в консоли браузера Firefox версии 124.0.2 мне выдаётся ошибка:
Firefox не может установить соединение с сервером ws://127.0.0.1:8000/message.
Как мне исправить эту ошибку?
